# spring & java web application - how to show the client the request is proccesing?

Tags: java, html, ajax, multithreading, jsp

- I have a Spring web application

  - Client - can click on a button - calling to POST request in the server
  - How I can show him that the request is running? (It can run for 5 secounds or 3 hours)
  - I did not know if I need to wrap my post method in THREAD or add Ajax to jsp file to dealing the button?

Flow:

1. Client insert name to the form and click "Scan"
2. scanRequest() mehtod called
3. justDoSomething() - Called from "scanRequest()" and start (serround in thred?)
4. doingSpesificThing() - Called from "justDoSomething()" - (Serround in thread?)

** I want Client sees his request is being processing by loading bar or any other sign for the main request & for each run of the "justDoSomething()"

Signs to Client - pennding, processing , finished / done

** I'd be happy if someone could direct me please

**Update: requestList form, selectedRequestForm**

- requestlist: where all user request displayed
- SelectedRequestList: where all request scan data displayed - each row - diffrenet status in scan..

JSP:

```
    <form:form method="POST" action="${contextPath}/scanRequest" modelAttribute="scanForm" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create new scan: </h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <spring:bind path="name">
                        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                            <form:input type="text" path="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" autofocus="true"></form:input>
                            <form:errors path="name"></form:errors>
                        </div>
                    </spring:bind>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="scanForm" value="${UserRequestDTO}" />
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Scan</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

  <form action="${contextPath}/requestlist" method="post">  
        <table class="table table-sm">
            <thead class="thead-inverse">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Id
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        \\**Status?** - How?..
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Show request
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <c:forEach items="${requestDTOList}" var="requestDTO">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        ${requestDTO.getId()}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${requestDTO.getName()}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden"  name="${_csrf.parameterName}"   value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                        <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="${contextPath}/showSelectedRequest/${requestDTO.getId()}" value="Query">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        </form>
  <h2>Selected Request:</h2>
    <h3>${RequestIdSelected}</h3>

    <form action="${contextPath}/SelectedRequestList" method="post">    
        <table id="selectedRequestListTable" class="sortable table table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="sorttable_nosort">
                        Image
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Titel
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Loading statues
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Match
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <c:forEach items="${selectedRequestListDTO}" var="selectedRequestDTO">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="${selectedRequestDTO.getImage()}" 
                             alt="${selectedRequestDTO.getId()}" 
                             style="width:128px;height:128px;"
                             border="0">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${selectedRequestDTO.getTitel()}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        \\ Status of the secound scan
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${selectedRequestPDTO.getMatch()} \\ Updated when the status is "done / completed / finished"
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/scanRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String scanRequest(@ModelAttribute("scanForm")UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        logger.info("scanRequest() - Start");

        \\**** My Method **** 
        \\ justDoSomething(); - **Update: request code**

        // Creating the Request and Start scanning 
        try {
            logger.info("scanRequest(): Creating the Request and Start scanning... ");

            // Loading the User Entity
            UserEntity currentUser = userService.findByName(securityService.findLoggedInUsername());


            // Checking if user was found
            if (currentUser == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("User not found - When Trying to load him for new request");
            }

            // Creating New Request
            RequestEntity currRequest = new RequestEntity(new Date(), currentUser, name);

            // Saving the RequestEntity
            requestService.save(currRequest);


            // ****  Calling the Function that manage the first scan *****
            // **** It Updading the DB after the scan result is done / 50 scan result each
            scannerService.scanFromURL_ToDB(currRequest, name, currentUser);

            // Saving The newuest scan results after loading
            requestService.save(currRequest);


            // ****  Calling the Function that manage the secound scan *****
            scannerService.scanFromURL_ToDB_InEachScanResult(currRequest, name, currentUser);


            // Setting the End time of the request
            currRequest.setEnd_DateTime(new Date());
            requestService.save(currRequest);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            logger.info(e.toString());
        }      

        logger.info("getUserRequests() - End");
        return "home";
    }

private void justDoSomething(){
    int n = 5;
    while (n >0)
    {
        \\****** Calling another method that doing spesific thing each time *******
        doingSpesificThing();
        n--;
    }
}

private void doingSpesificThing(){
    ***** Doing Somthing ******
}
```

Comment: You almost certainly want to finish the HTTP request and check back later with a status URL or dashboard page.

Comment: @chrylis I know but I can`t understand how.. i tried a lot of tutorial but nothing realy do the work

Answer (score 0):

A chrylis suggested, you should not wait for the request/job to finish if it takes as long as you said. This is really bad practice and will probably end with frustrated users or a non-responding web application.

First, let the backend accept the request, create a job from the data you received, store that job somewhere (e.g. database, in memory ...) and assign it a unique ID which you return *immediately* to the frontend.

Now, the job you stored is waiting to be run. Several options, either you start it in a separate `thread` before you send the response back to the frontend or you could wait for a scheduler to pick it up, send it to the remote super cluster in the data center or something else. Most important thing: it is detached from your (http) request.

When you process that job you could write status information in regular periods back to your storage. Always make sure that you are able to obtain the job and those status data by the unique ID you assigned in the first place.

As your frontend received that ID, it is able to poll information about the job anytime it wants to, even after a browser restart or a network breakdown :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i Update my controller request as you can see I insert TO the DB the request of the user, In "home.jsp" I have table that is the user Requests and there ii what to show the user each request - status..  I think in "requestlist" Form - each row - diffrenet request - is were all the status for each request will need to showed

Comment: Have you implemented a second method in your controller, that provides the status of your scan jobs? And does the ScannerService detach from the current thread in any way?

Comment: I still have not written the function that manages the threads and return their status.
This is one of my questions here how to do it right: / - I guess it will be static method.
And what do you mean if ScannerService detach the thread anyway?

Comment: Sorry Guyb, regarding your other questions here on SO, I'm guess you are just beginning with Spring. You're missing some basics regarding backend concurrency, which makes it really hard helping you here. What you need is someone to do pair-programming with you. I'd need much more insight in your architecture to help you with this. And even if I had, I'd be spending hours here writing comments, which StackOverflow is definitely not the proper platform to.

Comment: Thank you for honest answer, I know to program and i just need Example of somthing like that, I understad all the spring framework but this i new to me. I can contact you in mail or somthing?